# Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context on data filtering

Tags: c#

I am getting error saying `System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'ZikFunnelItemUpdate_Console.Models.Item'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'`

Please also check in picture for `deleteList, updateList, addList` same code working but on `deleteImageList` since i am using `db.ItemGalleries` to fetch and find data from database using entityframework i am getting following error. My question do you know any quick fix to solve this issue? Please ask if you have question. Please note: Item and ItemGallery ItemID is linked primary key

[image: pic]

Main code:

```
var EixistingItems = db.Items.Where(x => x.UserStoresID == uStore.UserStoresID).ToList();

                    var addList = new List<Item>();
                    var updateList = new List<Item>();
                    var deleteList = new List<Item>();
                    var deleteImageList = new List<ItemGallery>();

                    deleteList = EixistingItems.Where(ei => !MyItemList.Any(ni => ni.EbayID == ei.EbayID)).ToList();
                    updateList = EixistingItems.Where(ei => MyItemList.Any(ni => ni.EbayID == ei.EbayID)).ToList();
                    addList = MyItemList.Where(ni => !EixistingItems.Any(ei => ei.EbayID == ni.EbayID)).ToList();


                    deleteImageList = db.ItemGalleries.Where(ei => deleteList.Any(ni => ni.ItemID == ei.ItemID)).ToList();
```

Comment: What types are  `ni.ItemID` and `ei.ItemID`?

Comment: deleting related data would usually be better approached by having appropriate foreign keys with cascading deletes, rather than manually having to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select statement after where statement like

```
deleteImageList = db.ItemGalleries.Select(x=> new ItemGallery{/*Select Items*/}).Where(ei => deleteList.Any(ni => ni.ItemID == ei.ItemID)).Select(x=> new ItemGallery{/*Select Items*/}).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer makes absolutely no sense. It just creates a new object for each result.

Answer (score 0):

You can find list of `ItemID` from `deleteList` and check `.Contains` as below:

```
deleteListIds = deleteList.Select(ni => ni.ItemID).ToList();
deleteImageList = db.ItemGalleries.Where(ei => deleteListIds.Contains(ei.ItemID)).ToList();
```